# Linq to sql constantly returns null

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Participant.BackgroundTrainingID, 
  Location.TrainingSite
FROM Registration, ProgramLocation, Participant, Program, Location
WHERE ProgramLocation.LocationID = Location.LocationID 
  AND ProgramLocation.ProgramID=Registration.ProgramID 
  AND Registration.ParticipantID=Participant.ParticipantId
```

I wrote the following LINQ to SQL to match the query above:

```
var trainingsiteinfo = (from c in db.ProgramLocations 
                        from n in db.Registrations 
                        from l in db.Participants  
                        from h in db.Locations 
                        where c.LocationID == h.LocationID 
                          && c.ProgramID == n.ProgramID 
                          && n.ParticipantID == l.ParticipantId 
                        select new { 
                          h.TrainingSite, 
                          l.BackgroundTrainingID }).Distinct();
```

The SQL query works fine but LINQ constantly returns null.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns null"? `Distinct` doesn't return `null`. It can however return an empty enumeration, and your code could throw a `NullReferenceException`. Did you mean one of those?

Comment: I guess my debugging part was incorrect when I was testing but just fixed thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Linqer http://www.sqltolinq.com/ when i get out of ideas :-) Aswell it speeds up conversion jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your db context isn't going out of scope before you have bound your results. You can test this by adding `.ToList()` after your `.Distinct()` to force eager loading of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your linq code has an unclosed } bracket in the select statement